# Compiling Apache 2.4 mod_perl-2.0.11

Tags: linux, apache, perl, centos7, mod-perl

I have a environment with Apache 2.4.43 compiled manually by the following config:

```
"./configure" \
"--enable-so" \
"--enable-deflate" \
"--enable-cache" \
"--enable-mem-cache" \
"--enable-rewrite" \
"--enable-ssl" \
"--with-included-apr" \
"--enable-socache-memcache" \
"--with-mpm=prefork" \
"$@"
```

and now I'm trying to compiling mod_perl-2.0.11 with the following command:

perl Makefile.PL MP_APXS=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs

and I'm getting this error:

```
Can't locate ExtUtils/Embed.pm in @INC (@INC contains: lib Apache-Test/lib /root/perl5/lib/perl5/5.16.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /root/perl5/lib/perl5/5.16.3 /root/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /root/perl5/lib/perl5 /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at lib/Apache2/Build.pm line 28.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at lib/Apache2/Build.pm line 28.
Compilation failed in require at Makefile.PL line 38.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Makefile.PL line 38.
```

All perl dependency's are installed and I can't resolve this problem.

The S.O. is CentOS 7.

Comment: Where is ExtUtils::Embed installed?

Comment: I've installed ExtUtils with the following: yum install perl-ExtUtils-CBuilder perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker

Answer (score 1):

Ok, After a long search I found that I needed to install one more thing, this was the perl-ExtUtils-Embed, I thought that after installing with cpan all perl dependencies and a lot of perl packages this was already installed. Actually the comment made by choroba sparkled something in my head and I start to search differently until I found a post telling about:

```
yum install perl-ExtUtils-Embed
```

after that I could run the perl command:

```
perl Makefile.PL MP_APXS=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs
```